# Chat completions /v1/chat/completions results is very different than the ChatGPT result

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I find out the API /v1/chat/completions result is very different than the web page result.

This is the API response for Q: "content": "What is the birthday of George Washington"

```bash
    curl --location 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
        "model": "gpt-4",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": "What is the birthday of George Washington"
            }
        ]
    }'
```

```json
    "choices": [
            {
                "message": {
                    "role": "assistant",
                    "content": "George Washington was born on February 22, 1732."
                },
                "finish_reason": "stop",
                "index": 0
            }
        ]
```

And this is the result on the web page. You can see it is much longer.
[image]

Comment: The behavior you describe is expected. Using the API, you can set `    "temperature": 0.0` in your request to receive a deterministic response. However, if you attempt to set a temperature in ChatGPT web UI, it will tell you that you can't do that and suggest you use the API.

Comment: @busse How do I make temperature work at API to make the answer a bit longer like the web UI?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76597257/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, ChatGPT-4 is not willing to spill the beans either. While it is possible to tweak the temperature via API and find a good balance, I'd be curious as well what the default temperate on Web actually is.

Question for ChatGPT-4 via Web:
What is the default temperature when using ChatGPT via web instead of the API?

ChatGPT-4 answer:
The default temperature when using ChatGPT via web interface might not be explicitly stated. However, when using OpenAI's API, the default temperature is typically set to 0.7. This value provides a good balance between creativity and coherence. You can adjust the temperature to control the randomness of the generated text: a lower temperature (e.g., 0.2) makes the output more focused and deterministic, while a higher temperature (e.g., 1.0) makes it more random and creative. Keep in mind that the web interface and the API may have different default values or behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

When using OpenAI to [create completion](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) using GPT, you can turn some "knobs" to tune the results.

One of those knobs is the *temperature*.
A temperature is a number between 0 and 1. 0 is very focus and deterministic and 1 is very random.

To generate a longer text, you can also play with the *max_tokens* parameter.

But in your case I think you would need to adapt the prompt. Add something like *tell me more about him* and you should see the result improve already.

This was my test:

```bash
curl --location 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": "What is the birthday of George Washington? Tell me more about him."
            }
        ]
    }'
```

And the answer:

```json
{
    "object": "chat.completion",
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
    "usage": {
        "prompt_tokens": 22,
        "completion_tokens": 143,
        "total_tokens": 165
    },
    "choices": [
        {
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "George Washington's birthday is on February 22, 1732. He was the first president of the United States and is often known as the \"Father of His Country.\" Washington also led the Continental Army to victory over the British during the American Revolution. He is known for his strong leadership, unwavering commitment to his country, and the sacrifices he made to help establish the United States. Washington also played a key role in the creation of the U.S. Constitution, which remains a pillar of American democracy today. Throughout his life, Washington was known for his honesty, integrity, and commitment to the ideals of the American democratic system. His legacy has made him one of the most important figures in American history."
            },
            "finish_reason": "stop",
            "index": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to write detailed prompts. Don´t just write "Who is George Washington?". Better write "Who ist George Washington? What did he do? What about his childhood? What were his biggest achievements?..."

This way you should get a way longer response. Don´t forget to use line-breaks like "\n" between the questions when using the api.

This way we could get our responses from an average of 3000 characters to 6000.